# Getting Empty File when importing Custom Fields file

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am getting Empty File when importing a JSON with Custom Fields (ACF).
I tried all the options of changing the encoding of the JSON but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue is the add enctype="multipart/form-data to the form that uploads the file. 
The actual form is

```
<form method="post">
```

Replace it the browser inspector with:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have error reporting turned on, and you happen to have errors on your site, they can get printed in the first few lines of your json export file. Check your json file also for such a scenario. I have experienced this before so after removing the error lines in the export file or disabling error reporting, everything worked fine.